# Calling a normal function after multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a code which represents a car stimulation which basically reads gps points from a text file and determine the speed of the car.

Multiprocessing was used to read from multiple text files at the same time

I want to call a function right after the multiprocessing is ready to call the list where the traffic was detected.

Currently it is calling the function right before the multiprocessing and calling it 5 times (the number of multi processes) although these are not linked.

```
   def stimulation():
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-notraffic',))
    p1.start()
    #p1.join()
    p3 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-aldomoro2',))
    p3.start()
    #p3.join()
    p4 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-kappara1',))
    p4.start()
    #p4.join()
    p5 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-kappara2',))
    p5.start()


stimulation()
getStreetName()
```

All I want is for the getStreetName() method to be called after the stimulation

Comment: Hi is `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside simulation method?

Comment: Yes it is set in the stimulation method

Answer (score 1):

Each process you start reads the whole python file and executes is, so each your process calls those functions.
 
This `if __name__ == '__main__':` ensures that following block is executed only by main process
You need to wait for each process to finish (by calling `join()`) and then call your functions

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-notraffic',))
    p1.start()
    p3 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-aldomoro2',))
    p3.start()
    p4 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-kappara1',))
    p4.start()
    p5 = Process(target=getGPSPointsFromFile, args=('gpstest-traffic-kappara2',))
    p5.start() 
    p1.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
    stimulation()
    getStreetName()
```

Also, you may want to collect your processes in a list, then you can iterate over them and call join on each no matter how many processes you spawn

Comment: Thanks this helped :D